# Designing hash set in leetcode, code gives run time error

Tags: c++, runtime-error

Am trying to solve a question on designing HashSet.

> Design a HashSet without using any built-in hash table libraries.
>
> To be specific, your design should include these two functions:
>
> add(value): Insert a value into the HashSet.
>   contains(value) : Return whether the value exists in the HashSet or not.
>
> remove(value): Remove a value in the HashSet. If the value does not exist in the HashSet, do
>   nothing.
>
> Example:
>
> MyHashSet hashSet = new MyHashSet(); hashSet.add(1);
>   hashSet.add(2);          hashSet.contains(1);    // returns true
>   hashSet.contains(3);    // returns false (not found) hashSet.add(2);
>   hashSet.contains(2);    // returns true hashSet.remove(2);
>   hashSet.contains(2);    // returns false (already removed)
>
> Note:
>
> All values will be in the range of [1, 1000000]. The number of
>   operations will be in the range of [1, 10000]. Please do not use the
>   built-in HashSet library.

The following code runs fine locally, but fails on submission giving the error,

> Runtime Error Message:
>   reference binding to misaligned address 0x736c61662c657572 for type 'int', which requires 4 byte alignment
>
> Last executed input:
>   ["MyHashSet","add","remove","add","contains","add","remove","add","add","add","add"]
>   [[],[6],[4],[17],[14],[14],[17],[14],[14],[18],[14]]

```
class MyHashSet { public:
vector<vector<int>> setHash;
MyHashSet() {
    setHash.reserve(10000);
}

void add(int key) {
    int bucket = key % 10000;
    vector<int>::iterator it;
    it = find(setHash[bucket].begin(),setHash[bucket].end(),key);
    if(it == setHash[bucket].end()){
        setHash[bucket].push_back(key);
    }
}

void remove(int key) {
    int bucket = key % 10000;
    vector<int>::iterator it1;
    it1 = find(setHash[bucket].begin(),setHash[bucket].end(),key);
    if(it1 != setHash[bucket].end()){
        int index = distance(it1,setHash[bucket].begin());
        setHash[bucket].erase(setHash[bucket].begin()+index);
    }

}

/** Returns true if this set did not already contain the specified element */
bool contains(int key) {
    int bucket = key % 10000;
    vector<int>::iterator it2;
    it2 = find(setHash[bucket].begin(),setHash[bucket].end(),key);
        if(it2 != setHash[bucket].end()){
            return true;
        }

    return false;
}
```

};

I suspect its due to a memory issue. But couldn't able to figure out as i am still learning the fundamentals of c++.

Comment: The judge seems to have been kind and provided the breaking inputs.You should write yourself a simple `main` that executes those inputs and see what happens for yourself. If you have already done this, add it to the question.

Comment: `int index = distance(it1,setHash[bucket].begin());` this looks strange. Shouldn't you replace arguments in `distance`?

Comment: Handy reading [`std::vector::reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) and [`std::vector::resize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize). After reading, ask yourself, "Am I using the correct one?"

Comment: *The following code runs fine locally* -- Replace your `setHash[bucket]` with `setHash.at(bucket)`, and you will see it no longer run fine locally.  As a matter of fact, the `std::out_of_range` exception thrown will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: @user4581301 changing from std::vector::reserve to std::vector::resize made it work. After reading about these functions, I understand that 'reserve' fixes the size of the vector with no possibility of reallocation. which is why I get the 'Misaligned address error' probably because there is no more space. 'resize' is more appropriate for my case as I need space for fixed number of elements with the possibility of reallocation. Thanks!

Comment: "vector with no possibility of reallocation" Not quite. What it does is preallocates storage without constructing an element and updating the count of elements. You can then use the push and emplace functions without incurring a resize until you exceed the reserved capacity. It can be reallocated. Your program failed because `setHash[bucket]` had been allocated but did not contain a properly constructed `vector<int>`.`setHash[bucket].push_back(key);` would write an `int` into some random location in memory that was not appropriately aligned to handle an `int`

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to fix your implementation, I'd heed the advice in the comments.

If you're looking to learn about C++ and solve the problem in an optimal way, I'd use [`std::bitset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/).  The fact they give you the defined input range [1,1000000] leads me to believe they're looking for something like this.

This might fall into the category of built-in hash table libraries so [here is a potential implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/86623/c-bitset-implementation).

```
class MyHashSet {
public:
    void add(int key) {
        flags.set(key);
    }
    void remove(int key) {
        flags.reset(key);
    }
    bool contains(int key) const {
        return flags[key];
    }
private:
    bitset<1000000+1> flags;
};
```

On my platform, this takes up ~16kB (as opposed to 30kB+ for 10000 vectors). It also requires no dynamic memory allocation.

If you consider this off-topic or cheating, please provide the title/number of the LeetCode problem so I can work on your code draft using their test cases. I'm also studying hash tables right now so it'd be a win-win.